# Erroneous graph, values are different but the plot is same, what to do?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Trying to plot some data from text file, the values are different but the plots overlap in the end result. The code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
scale=2.00,
xlabel={\large$\frac{E_s}{N_o}$ \normalsize},
ylabel={$P_b(e)$},
grid=major,
legend pos=outer north east,
legend cell align = left]

\addplot[color=black,mark=circle,y=ber1,x=eb] table {SISO_4.txt};
\addplot[color=black,thick,y=ber2,x=eb] table {SISO_4.txt};
\addplot[color=black,mark=diamond,y=ber3,x=eb] table {SISO_4.txt};

\legend{BER[1],BER[2],BER[3]}

\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Probability of Bit Error vs. Signal to Noise Ratio \large$\frac{E_s}{N_o}$} % title 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And the file SISO.txt is like this:

```
eb  ber0        ber1        ber2        ber3
0   7.90E-02    7.84E-02    1.17E-03    2.48E-03
1   5.62E-02    5.62E-02    2.64E-04    5.41E-04
2   3.76E-02    3.73E-02    4.40E-05    1.02E-04
3   2.29E-02    2.28E-02    2.00E-06    5.50E-06
4   1.26E-02    1.25E-02    0.00E+00    1.00E-06
5   6.03E-03    5.92E-03    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
6   2.37E-03    2.40E-03    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
7   7.37E-04    7.47E-04    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
8   2.00E-04    1.93E-04    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
9   4.00E-05    3.10E-05    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
10  1.00E-06    7.00E-06    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
```

But the output plot is like this:

[image]

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the column specifications into the `table` options. See below. Note that I have changed several things:

1. The [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package loads the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package, so loading both is not necessary
2. The [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplo0ts) package loads the [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz) package, so loading both is not necessary
3. `circle` is not a valid mark shape. The correct mark for a filled circle is `*` and for an open circle is `o`.
4. You should have the `compat` option for `pgfplots` set. I've added version `1.11`, the most recent as of this answer
5. Note that it is not recommended to only use `[h]` to specify the location of a `figure`. (I need to find a reference for this)

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
scale=2.00,
xlabel={\large$\frac{E_s}{N_o}$ \normalsize},
ylabel={$P_b(e)$},
grid=major,
legend pos=outer north east,
legend cell align = left]

\addplot[color=black,mark=o] table[y=ber1,x=eb] {SISO_4.txt};
\addplot[color=black,thick] table[y=ber2,x=eb] {SISO_4.txt};
\addplot[color=black,mark=diamond] table[y=ber3,x=eb] {SISO_4.txt};

\legend{BER[1],BER[2],BER[3]}

\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Probability of Bit Error vs. Signal to Noise Ratio \large$\frac{E_s}{N_o}$} % title
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```